# clustering with kmeans in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

i want to use a k-means algorithm to cluster some sort of sellling statistics .
Here is an example of how my csv file looks like:

```
articleNumber, quantity, date
101,           15,       2018-07-09
101,           30,       2018-07-08
...
102,           10,       2018-07-09
102,           5,        2018-07-09
...
```

My goal is to find similiar article groups (e.g. good selling in summer) and match future articles into those groups.
What i did so far:
I read the csv file into a pandas dataframe:

```
data = pd.readcsv(("data.csv"), parse_dates=["DATE"], nrows=1000)
```

Where i need help to deal with:

- Normalize data: i tried using the L1 and L2 normalization from the sklearn-package as well as i tried to use the dataframe.pctchange from pandas. How can i get the percentual change from day one to day two, day two to day three and so on. I do not want to compare/match to real quantites, i want to compare based on the percentual change or 'shape'.
- Get a single dataframe for each dataset of article numbers from the main dataframe 'data' (maybe an array of dataframes that can be passed to the k-means algorithm)

Comment: Why do you want do work with the percentual change instead of a normalized quantity?

Comment: i dont want to work on the percentual change, i just thought that this would be a good measure for my use case. a normalized quantity would be fine as well.